# Does email provider scan mails for viruses?

Tags: malware, email, antivirus

Imagine I am on me@outlook.com and I send a mail to him@outlook.com with an `eicar.txt` as an attachement. Will the email be stopped because it contains the `eicar.txt` ?

In case there is an email scanning mechanism, how can I know which antivirus is used by the email provider to scan the mails ?

For instance does outlook use Microsoft defender to scan the content of a mail ? How can I know what antivirus is used by gmail for example ? Is this information public or should we dig deeper with osint and other tools ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think most of the technologies used are apparently proprietary and custom built, but nothing is preventing you from spinning up your own instance of an email server with ClamAV or similar software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Are you sure the technologies are custom built ? Normally making you own AV with signature detection is quite expensive. Isn't it much cheaper for mail providing companies to have a contract with kaspersky for example to scan their mail ? @SirMuffington

Comment: And even if the information about the AV is secret, isn't there ways for a malicious attacker to identify the AV used by OSINT or other types of investigations and experimentation ? @SirMuffington

Comment: I don't know what decision making process was made by the management of the big companies... But there must've been a good reason to spin up their own solution... You could in theory identify something from quite a big number of samples, but that wouldn't quite show how it works inside... What's your goal with your question btw? This seems to go beyond the blue team goal...

Comment: My goal is to see to what extend attacker can gain information about the AV of a mail provider by interacting in a Blackbox context. Don't worry it is purely academics. People warned me I should give up because there is little information and documentation about this specific subject ...@SirMuffington

Comment: And what would the attacker do with this information exactly?..

Comment: He can know for example that this company is using technology from kaspersky for mail scanning, which is basically divulging some secret information. So he only focus on bypassing kaspersky defences if he wants to attack a company...

Comment: From a blue team perspective this looks like a lot of effort for not a whole lotta information. And cybercriminals usually go for the low hanging fruit as research and statistics shows.

Answer (score 1):

> Does email provider scan mails for viruses?

This entirely depends on the mail provider. But the bigger ones include spam, phishing and also malware protection. Which technology they use and maybe even the specific products are usually not public information.

Comment: So basically there is no way to know what antivirus they are using ? Even by sending malware samples to check if they are being detected ?

Comment: or maybe sending a bugged file that notifies us when it is scanned ?

Comment: How do you expect for a file to send out packets or anything that would alert from being analyzed? That's like a beacon in Ghidra - I doubt that's currently technically possible...

Comment: @Rudeus: It is not even clear if they use any of the established products, or a combination of many products and even combined with their own technology. You might make some assumptions by probing with specific files which you can compare how known antivirus engines detect these.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich a part from using virtustotal and comparing detection, I thought of zipping eicar with gradually strong password. I heard that some antivirus engine attempts to crack the zip file then scan the content. Do you have other method or ideas ? Public database of signature for antivirus maybe ?

Comment: @Rudeus: *"Do you have other method or ideas"* - using different interpretation of the same data might be a strategy. File formats like ZIP often allow variations which gets interpreted differently by various tools. Or polyglot files, like a zip file (allows junk at beginning) prefixed with gzip (allows junk at end) etc. Detecting different interpretations might be used to somehow fingerprint the engine and then compare this to what one can see in virustotal.